# How to initiate mongodb replica set using nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I'm running the following code for mongodb replica set initialization:

```
try {
  const mongoClient: MongoClient = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://mongodb:27017', {replicaSet: "rs0"});
  const mongoDb: Db = new Db(mongoClient, "admin");
  const response = await mongoDb.admin().command({ replSetInitiate: {} }, {})
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
}
```

However getting an error:

> MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms

And so for any other command

`rs.initiate()` from mongosh solves the problem for other commands, but I need a way to initiate replica set during the runtime in nodejs

It turns out some kind of deadlock, replica set initialization requires connection to DB, and connection to DB requires replica set initialization

mongodb version: 4.2,

mongodb npm package version: 4.10.0

UPD: startup logs added

```
I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=mongodb
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.22
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: eef44cd56b1cc11e5771736fa6cb3077e0228be2
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "*" }, replication: { replSet: "rs0" } }
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten]
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=12243M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1665036200:416720][1:0x7f8baf77eb00], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)
I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables. Logging enabled? 0
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Timestamp monitor starting
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow Control is enabled on this deployment.
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.startup_log with generated UUID: bd81a433-4ec3-48df-b67d-e37c47c24343 and options: { capped: true, size: 10485760 }
I  INDEX    [initandlisten] index build: done building index _id_ on ns local.startup_log
I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.replset.oplogTruncateAfterPoint with generated UUID: 0aa8d2bd-f0c7-4703-8641-a029cde77b48 and options: {}
I  INDEX    [initandlisten] index build: done building index _id_ on ns local.replset.oplogTruncateAfterPoint
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.replset.minvalid with generated UUID: 370687e5-79d9-4365-b6e0-b05cd4ab31f0 and options: {}
I  INDEX    [initandlisten] index build: done building index _id_ on ns local.replset.minvalid
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.replset.election with generated UUID: 4f892389-a4c5-4abb-b8e6-d5bdb282dc9f and options: {}
I  INDEX    [initandlisten] index build: done building index _id_ on ns local.replset.election
I  REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local initialized voted for document at startup.
I  REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local Rollback ID document at startup. Creating one.
I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.system.rollback.id with generated UUID: 1049c565-09b2-4bf9-95c3-ade2162773f5 and options: {}
I  INDEX    [initandlisten] index build: done building index _id_ on ns local.system.rollback.id
I  REPL     [initandlisten] Initialized the rollback ID to 1
I  REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup;  NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset
I  CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions refresh interval: Replication has not yet been configured
I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 0.0.0.0
I  CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval: config.system.sessions does not exist
I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.21.0.7:56492 #1 (1 connection now open)
I  NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 172.21.0.7:56492 conn1: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.7.3" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2" }, platform: "'Node.js v12.22.7, LE (legacy)" }
```

Comment: What does the `mongod` log file show when the application is executed? I'm also curious about why you need to do this during the runtime of the nodejs program, but that's really tangential to the question itself.

Comment: The main idea is dynamically define whether system (which uses mongodb) will run in standalone mode, or as backup system. If mongodb instance already initialized, I can not add it to primary system mongodb replica set

Comment: Added logs to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

directConnection option was missing

```
try {
  const mongoClient: MongoClient = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_RO_URI || 'mongodb://mongodb:27017', {replicaSet: "rs0", directConnection: true});
  const mongoDb: Db = new Db(mongoClient, "admin");
  const response = await mongoDb.admin().command({ replSetInitiate: {} }, {})
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
}
```

Comment: Nice.  I was just typing up an answer but will leave one of the important observations here - you mention driver version `4.10.0` in your question but the log shows `3.7.3`. Look into that, especially since there is a [note about `3.7` in the compatibility docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/compatibility/#footnote-unified-topology). I also think it doesn't really make sense to have the replica set information in the connection string when it hasn't been initiated yet, but if simply adding `directConnection` works then great!

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely hitting the timeout shown here:

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/reference/faq/

```
  const mongoClient: MongoClient = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://mongodb:27017', {replicaSet: "rs0", connectTimeoutMS: SET_VALUE_HERE});
```

Comment: Timeout isn't the issue. Even 2 minutes timeout doesn't solve the problem.